# "You can't be charged with the same crime twice" is the moral of the story. But I can't remember the title

Tags: identify-this-movie

It was one of those films you watch on TV and don't pay much attention to the title.  It's about a man who sets up the following trap for his wife: he disappears and after having prepared all the evidence that it was a murder and that his wife had motives to do it. The wife is tried, is charged with murder, and spends like 15 years in prison.  When she is released a phone call from an insurance company makes her suspect her husband is alive and it was all a set up.  She becomes determined to track him and she eventually finds him alive and well in California. Overcome by hatred, she buys a gun and meets him face to face. She points the gun at him and says she is going to kill him. He tries to convince her that she is going to ruin her life. That's when she says: "I've studied all about it. You can't be charged with the same crime twice" and shoots him down.  If anyone knows the title...

Comment: Note that legally, this plot utterly fails. Killing him two different times is two different crimes.

Comment: @PeteBecker How do you logically kill someone twice?  Or am I being silly in thinking that there's some correspondence between logic and law?

Comment: @jamesdlin - obviously you don't. Read the plot summary in the question. Faking a murder is not a get-out-of-jail-free card, and that's perfectly logical.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm quite familiar with (and am a fan) of this particular movie.  I'm just saying that "Killing him two different times" is not itself a logical statement.  Really it's just "Two separate incidents are two separate crimes/charges".

Comment: @jamesdlin - apparently you read too much about the legal system into my comment about the movie's idiotic premise.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The film you're looking for is *[Double Jeopardy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Jeopardy_%28film%29)*:

> *Double Jeopardy* is a 1999 American mystery-thriller film directed by Bruce Beresford and starring Tommy Lee Jones, Ashley Judd, and Bruce Greenwood. The film is about a woman who is framed for the murder of her husband.

It's a really good film, in my mind.

Double Jeopardy is also the legal term for this.

> Double jeopardy is a procedural defense that forbids a defendant from being tried again on the same (or similar) charges following a legitimate acquittal or conviction. In common law countries, a defendant may enter a peremptory plea of autrefois acquit or autrefois convict (autrefois means "in the past" in French), meaning the defendant has been acquitted or convicted of the same offence and hence that they cannot be retried under the principle of double jeopardy.